# How to calculate coordinates of two points according to the angle of rotation and the distance between them?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, rotations

Suppose 2 cases:

Situation 1) I have 2 points, one at (0,0,0) and other at (x, y, z) at a distance d

Situation 2) I have 2 points, one at (0,0,0) and other at (x', 0, z') at a distance d.

How could I get an expression for x' and z' as a function of alpha angle (see Example attached) maintaining the distance d of both points.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvprQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

This essentially means the two points lie on the sphere centered at the origin, with radius $d$. i.e. $$x^2+y^2+z^2=(x’)^2 +(z’)^2 $$ Any pair $(x’,z’)$ which satisfies this equation will be good to go, the solution is not unique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @tavish ! I have one question, if I didn't change the point in z of the second point in the second situation (that is, I would have a point in (0,0,0) and another in (x', 0, z)), how could I get x' as function of alfa?

Comment: @EmersonPL If $z’=z$, then $$x’=\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ It doesn’t depend on $\alpha$. What is $\alpha$ anyway? In the figure, is it perhaps the angle between the line through $(0,0,0)$ and $(x,y,z)$ and the $x$ axis?

Comment: Alpha would be the angle between the distance d (between the two points in 3d) and the distance of the two points in x. I'm bad at drawing, I'm sorry.
I think the expression that you mentioned meets what i need. Thanks for the answer and time!

Comment: @Emerson P L You’re welcome!